# Teapot Riddle no.46 (fan made)

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

**Teapot riddle rules:**
I have one word which has several (2 or more) meanings.
Each of the meanings is a teapot (first, second ...)
You try to figure out the word with my Hints

First Hint:

> My first teapot is forceful
>  My second teapot is enticing
>  My third teapot is reneging

Second Hint:

> My first teapot draws
>  My second teapot also draws
>  My third teapot cuts off

Third Hint:

> My first teapot requires strength
>  My second teapot requires charm
>  My third teapot requires resolve

Fourth Hint:

> My first teapot might be done to a pig
>  My second teapot isn't something normally attributed to a pig
>  My third teapot might result in someone being called a pig

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Possible answer:

> Pull?

First Hint:

> To be forceful by pulling someone or something.
>  To metaphorically pull people towards you with charisma.
>  You could renege on a deal by pulling out.

Second Hint:

> Draws: "to cause to move in a particular direction by or as if by a pulling force" (dictionary.com)
>  Draws people in with charisma
>  Cuts off by pulling out of a deal/pulling a product line.

Third Hint:

> Requires strength to physically pull something.
>  Requires charm to metaphorically pull people in.
>  Requires resolve as people might get angry when you pull out of a deal? (Not sure about this one)

Fourth Hint:

> You can pull a pig around, but that isn't very nice. (Or make pulled pork - thanks WAF!)
>  You probably wouldn't want to attract or entice a pig.
>  As above, people might get angry and call you a pig when you pull their  favourite product.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! For resolve, maybe along the lines of rot13(univat gur erfbyir gb chyy guebhtu)

Comment: 4a could be a reference to a manner of food preparation.

Comment: That's a good idea for the resolve clue @Dorrulf, but I thought each teapot number was constant across the clues? I'm not sure it fits completely with the other clues using that meaning.

Comment: I don't know if phrases/phrasal verbs are admissible if only the verb part is shared, but maybe these could be specifically applied to rot13(n genpgbe chyy, nggenpgvat chrevyl ebznagvpnyyl, chyyvat gur cyht). Although that would require 4b and 4c to switch places to fit nicely, so it's not a comprehensive suggestion.

Comment: Brilliant! Not every explanation what I was thinking but the 3 definitions are correct so well done.

Answer (score 3):

Shot in the dark but would the word be

> Drag?

First Hint:

> To be forceful by 'dragging' someone or something.
>  To entice to someone by dressing in 'drag'.
>  Reneges by being 'dragged' out of an agreement of sorts (a bit of a stretch, admittedly).

Second Hint:

> Draws like taking a 'drag' on a cigarette.
>  Draws by 'dragging' a writing utensil across paper.
>  Cuts off by 'dragging' someone or something away from others or other objects.

Third Hint:

> Requires strength to 'drag' something.
>  Requires charm to 'drag' or "influence other people" (informal).
>  Requires resolve because things may 'drag on' for a while.

Definition used: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/drag

Comment: Staggeringly close, but not quite.

Comment: Argh! I gotta wrack my brain a bit more than :>

Answer (score 0):

May it be a ...

> **twist** : the act of twisting something, the dance, and the unexpected development in some story.

First Hint:

> *My first teapot is forceful*
>      indeed, you need some kind of strength
>  *My second teapot is enticing*
>      Unless it's my older brother dancing....
>  *My third teapot is reneging*
>      ... hmm.. not sure it is suited here :(

Second Hint:

> *My first teapot draws*
>  If you are the towel : it does!
>  *My second teapot also draws*
>  You draw your partener from one foot to the other
>  *My third teapot cuts off*
>  ... the story mainline, indeed!

Third Hint:

> *My first teapot requires strength*
>  here again!
>  *My second teapot requires charm*
>  Not including my brother...
>  *My third teapot requires resolve*
>  When it is about your own story!

Fourth Hint:

> *My first teapot might be done to a pig*
>  Either it is about its tail, or about what you are about to perform with its neck
>  *My second teapot isn't something normally attributed to a pig*
>  ... did I mention my brother?
>  *My third teapot might result in someone being called a pig*
>  Once again, if it's related to you story.. let's say a sudden change in partnership... about your brother and you wife, for example!